# How to remove similar footer from many documents with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to clean like 18000 documents to train a word2vec classifier. A sample document is like :

```
From: shou@logos.asd.sgi.com (Tom Shou)
Subject: Ford Explorer 4WD - do I need performance axle?

We're considering getting a Ford Explorer XLT with 4WD and we have the
following questions (All we would do is go skiing -- no off-roading):

1. With 4WD, do we need the "performance axle" - (limited slip axle).
Its purpose is to allow the tires to act independently when the tires
are on different terrain. 

2. Do we need the all-terrain tires (P235/75X15) or will the
all-season (P225/70X15) be good enough for us at Lake Tahoe?


Thanks,


Tom

-- *(there maybe --- also)*


===========================================================================*(only one of the two boundaries made with ===== may be present(like sometimes only the top boundary is present)  in some cases and may differ in length)* 

        Tom Shou            Silicon Graphics
    shou@asd.sgi.com        2011 N. Shoreline Blvd. 
    415-390-5362            MS 8U-815 
    415-962-0494 (fax)      Mountain View, CA 94043

===========================================================================
```

So i need to remove the footer part. I am able to remove the From and Subject lines (the first two lines from the document with regex) . But i am not able to remove this part:

```
-- 


    ===========================================================================

            Tom Shou            Silicon Graphics
        shou@asd.sgi.com        2011 N. Shoreline Blvd. 
        415-390-5362            MS 8U-815 
        415-962-0494 (fax)      Mountain View, CA 94043

    ===========================================================================
```

Now some footers are just having two dashes or three dashes like:

```
-- 


            Tom Shou            Silicon Graphics
        shou@asd.sgi.com        2011 N. Shoreline Blvd. 
        415-390-5362            MS 8U-815 
        415-962-0494 (fax)      Mountain View, CA 94043
```

or

```
  --- 


                Tom Shou            Silicon Graphics
            shou@asd.sgi.com        2011 N. Shoreline Blvd. 
            415-390-5362            MS 8U-815 
            415-962-0494 (fax)      Mountain View, CA 94043
```

or sometimes it can have _ or + instead of ==== like :

```
   --(this maybe --- or may not exist at all but then the below ______ lines will be there) 


 ________________________________________________________________________(this can be + also)

                Tom Shou            Silicon Graphics
            shou@asd.sgi.com        2011 N. Shoreline Blvd. 
            415-390-5362            MS 8U-815 
            415-962-0494 (fax)      Mountain View, CA 94043

 _________________________________________________________________________
```

I am not very good at regex but i  tried to remove with a wrong regex like `((_|-|=|\+){2,})(.|\n)*` but i didnt consider that there are overlaps of -- within the content so it removed the content also which i dont want. 
Like in the content there is a line(4th line) with 2 dashes `All we would do is go skiing -- no off-roading):`. So it removed everything including and after -- which i dont want. I only want to remove the footer.

So i wanted to know what should my regex be like or what method should i use to clean the footer even if -- or --- is not always present but (there is a box made with either ______ or ++++++ or =========) or vice versa.

Please help
thanks in advance

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'(?ms)^[ \t]*--+.*', '', text)`

Comment: See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lohL12/1).

Comment: Or maybe Wiktor's suggestion with your alternation added `(?ms)^[ \t]*(?:_|-|=|\+){2,}.*` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CECcUr/1)

Comment: In that case, I think `re.sub(r'(?ms)^[ \t]*([-_=+])\1+.*', '', text)` is what is meant.

Comment: Thats even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(?ms)^[ \t]*([-_=+])\1+.*', '', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lohL12/1)

**Details**

- `(?ms)` - `re.M` (`^` will match the start of a line) and `re.DOTALL` (`.` will match any chars) are enabled
- `^` - start of a line
- `[ \t]*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces (you may also use `[^\S\r\n]*` for that)
- `([-_=+])` - Group 1: a `-`, `_`, `=`, or `+`
- `\1+` - the same char as captured into Group 1, one or more times
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I had tried it. It only sometimes doesnt work. So how can this be  modified so that i can give individual occurence specifications for   [-_=+] like if either (- is more than 3 times) or (= is more than 5 times) or (_ is more than 4 times) or (+ is more than 5 times)

Comment: Also i wanted to know that is there a way to just check in the second half of the document. Because footers are generally below so is there a way to search for footers only in the below 50-80% of the document if the document has lets say more than 50 -70 lines or more . So i want to choose depending on how big the document if i ll be applying the method to scan only the lower parts of the document.

Comment: Regarding 1), `(?ms)^[ \t]*(?:-{3,}|={5,}|_{4,}|\+{5,}).*` [might work](https://regex101.com/r/lohL12/2). As for 2), no idea what you mean. You can see that `.*` matches the rest of the string. If you want to limit that part to 70 lines only, remove `s` from `(?ms)` and replace `.*` with `.*(?:\n.*){0,69}\Z`.

Comment: for 2) i mean that - lets say the document has 70 lines so the footer has a probability of only being in the lower part of the document(last 35 lines or 30 lines) . So how to search/apply-regex only after the first 35 lines.

Comment: @userrk Calculate that number in code, then build the regex dynamically to put the desired value into `{0,x}` quantifier.